# Debugger в pycharm встал, не продолжает отладку. Отладка не продолжается

Tags: python, pycharm, отладка, отладчик

В общем, хотел разобраться в коде коллеги с помощью отладчика. Запускаю его, ловит ошибку в импорте и всё. Сервер работает, логика работает, а отладчик дальше ошибки не идёт.

в консоли:

```
    `Connected to pydev debugger (build 213.7172.26)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'material'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаю на степ, все пропадает с дебагера и все. Как быть? Может неправильно пользуюсь?

Comment: код приводите в виде текста тут. Не перепечатывать же его вручную нам.

Comment: А как вы собрались разобраться с кодом коллеги, если не понимаете, что ошибка в импорте? Библиотек нет, о чём дебагер сообщает и программа валится

Comment: т.е. отсутствие библиотек не дает дебагеру продолжить отладку? Повторюсь, что сервер работает и функции ниже по коду отрабатывают.

Comment: Если все работает, а вы знаете, что библиотеки нет и она вам не нужна, то просто попробуйте закомментировать строку и разбираться без неё.

Comment: Если закомментировать, выдает ошибку, что нет библиотеки.

Comment: Дебагер не работает, т.к, ошибка на этой строчке конкретно. Нужно закомментировать все, что с ней связано и будет счастье

Comment: Возможно, криво настроен дебагер.
material это локальный модуль? пайчарм его красным пометил, либо не правильно импортится относительно рабочей директории, либо модуля нет